# To preserve or delete contents of edit boxes

Tags: delphi

To preserve the contents of the edit boxes, what would be a better approach:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if checkBox1.Checked then begin
    edit1.text:='';
    edit2.text:='';
end else begin
edit1.text := edit1.Text;
edit2.text := edit2.text;
end
end;
```

or

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if checkBox1.Checked = True then begin
    edit1.text:='';
    edit2.text:='';
end else begin
abort;
end
end;
```

or ? Learning ...

EDIT : If I understood you right, this might be done like this :

```
if cxcheckbox1.Checked = True then begin
end else begin
edit1.text:='';
edit2.text:='';
```

Comment: Preserve the context of the edit boxes to what/for what? And what's the function of CheckBox1? Giving it a better name helps, maybe it should be named something like CheckBoxClearEdits? And 'abort' is unnecessary. If you want to do nothing, do nothing.

Comment: This is just learning stuff, to see how things work.Does not abort terminate the loop?

Comment: @user3351050 What loop?

Comment: @user3351050 There is no loop in your code. Read your code as natural language: if condition do begin... end. That looks like it's enough for your purpose. Unless there's something specific you want to do when the condition is not true. But again, what do you want to happen? I suggest your first address all comments by **writing a better question** (edit it), instead of shooting off comments.

Comment: @ David Heffernan -I meant if then else.@Jan Doggen - so I dont have to write anything if I dont want nothing changed ? I thought you had to write something ...

Comment: If you omit the `else`, nothing will be done if the `condition` evaluates false.

Comment: Regarding your edit, that completely changes the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if checkBox1.Checked then begin
    edit1.Text := '';
    edit2.Text := '';
  end;
end;
```

There's no need for an `else` clause because you want to do nothing in it. There's no point writing `edit1.Text := edit1.Text` because that makes no change to the contents of the edit control.

In real code you would be well advised to give names to your controls that make it easy to 
work out the purpose of the control when reading the code.

Finally, it is idiomatic to write `if b` rather than `if b=True` for boolean expressions. To test the negated condition you write `if not b` rather than `if b=False`. Of course, your way works fine, but other programmers will find it hard to read.